# How to add local pdf file in jsfiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I want to display one pdf file(sample.pdf) in jsfiddle using html Object tag which is present in my local. Where i have to keep my sample pdf file in jsfiddle to diplay?.
Please help me to do this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santhoshcd/9ngm5Lke/)

```html
<object data="sample.pdf#page=1&amp;zoom=75,0,0" type="application/pdf" standby="File is loading" height="500px" width="97%" id='object_tag'>
        <params name="src" value="sample.pdf#page=1&amp;zoom=75,0,0" id="params_tag">
          <embed src="sample.pdf#page=1&amp;zoom=75,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="97%" width="97%" id="embed_tag">
        </params>
      </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to upload the file to the internet.  JSfiddle does not host files, so you will need to use a third-party file hosting service.  Type "temporary file hosting" into google, and find one that looks good.  You then upload your file to the service, and the service returns a URL, which you will use where I have "URL" in the code below.

```
<object data="sample.pdf#page=1&amp;zoom=75,0,0" type="application/pdf" standby="File is loading" height="500px" width="97%" id='object_tag'>
    <params name="src" value="sample.pdf#page=1&amp;zoom=75,0,0" id="params_tag">
      <embed src="URL#page=1&amp;zoom=75,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="97%" width="97%" id="embed_tag">
    </params>
  </object>
```

Comment: Thanks. But i did not get any hosting site which is giving url contains .pdf at end. Ex https://domain_name/file_name.pdf. Can you tell me the site link which is giving proper pdf url?